# p5js insert canvas as table element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a two-part project with p5 - which will contain a menu tab and the canvas in a table. But it appears that p5 auto-inserts the canvas into the document that it's imported to, thus appears below any html.

Is there any way to manually draw the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

The p5 editor inserts the canvas at the end of the `<body></body>` tag before runtime, so the canvas can't be put into a table with p5's editor. It can be resolved *outside* of the editor by doing the following.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>sample text</td>
        <td><canvas id="defaultCanvas" class="" width="400" height="540" style="width: 400px; height: 540px;"></canvas></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```